# SHA1 sum on multilanguage strings

Tags: java, javascript, android, node.js

I have an android app that comminicates with a nodejs server via http.

To each request I add a SHA1 checksum that iterates over the key value pairs I'm sending to the server so that it would validate it on arrival.

I have tested this and it works okay as long as the values I'm sending are in English. Sending a request that contains a string value in Hebrew for example or that includes an unstandard character (like é, ç or à) will fail the request base on a checksum mismatch.

The checksum is calculated first in the andoird client (JAVA) and than in the nodejs server for verification.

I eliminated the possibility that this is caused due to the Right To Left nature of the Hebrew language by sending a single letter value, and it still failed.

What could cause this? I assume this might be because the encoding of a JAVA string for non standard characters is different from that of nodejs. But how can I solve this?

Here is the relevant code from the server side:

```
var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');
while (fieldsPointer < allFields.length
           || filesPointer < allFiles.length) {
    shasum.update(fieldKey);
    let fieldKey = allFields[fieldsPointer];
    shasum.update(fieldKey);
    let fieldValue = fields[allFields[fieldsPointer]];
    shasum.update(fieldValue);
}
```

and the client side:

```
   try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        for(Entry<String, Object> entry : allParams.entrySet()) {
            md.update(entry.getKey().getBytes());
            if(entry.getValue() instanceof String) {
                String value = (String) entry.getValue();
                md.update(value.getBytes());
            } else (...) // some other instance checking for non String values
        }
        String checksum = bytesToHex(md.digest());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Be sure your JS code is also operating on bytes, and bytes created using the _same character encoding_ as used on the Java side.  Your Java code doesn't seem to specify a character set, so you're getting the default encoding which may not be what you think it is.

Comment: Apart from ensuring that encoding of the charset is the same, is the order of the key, values fixed? I cannot tell this with the current code snippet. Otherwise, you might want to be sure this is the case.

Comment: You're only showing the calculation of the digest, but not the way the data is passed from the client to the server. This is critical to understanding how it is encoding the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research based on Williams's comment.

It turns out all I need to do was to change this:

```
shasum.update(fieldValue);
```

to this:

```
shasum.update(fieldValue, 'utf8');
```

as stated in the nodejs crypto documentation for hash encoding: http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_update_data_input_encoding

While this works, it is also a good idea to state the charset in the client side, as William stated in the comment below.

I did this by changing this:

```
md.update(value.getBytes());
```

to this

```
md.update(value.getBytes("utf8"));
```

Comment: You probably need to do something similar on the Java side, which is UTF-16 internally.

Comment: And don't forget to do the same for your _keys_, too.  (Unless you're absolutely sure that they're always ASCII.)